# Cannot write linq sorted list to a textfile

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the code. When I write the sorted List to the file What I get in the file is System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[MembersList.Member,System.String]

```
enter code here 
 List<Member> data = new List<Member>();
 int itemcount = 0;            
 string[] memberinfo = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sirslist\\data.txt"); 
 for (int i = itemcount; i < memberinfo.Length / 14; i++)
 {
     data.Add(new Member
     {
         BadgeNo = memberinfo[itemcount],
         LastName = memberinfo[itemcount + 1],
         FirstName = memberinfo[itemcount + 2],
         MiddleInitial = memberinfo[itemcount + 3],
         Nickname = memberinfo[itemcount + 4],
         WifeName = memberinfo[itemcount + 5],
         Address = memberinfo[itemcount + 6],
         ZipCode = memberinfo[itemcount + 7],
         Phone = memberinfo[itemcount + 8],
         Email = memberinfo[itemcount + 9],
         WeddingMonth = memberinfo[itemcount + 10],
         BirthDate = memberinfo[itemcount + 11],
         Employment = memberinfo[itemcount + 12],
         Interests = memberinfo[itemcount + 13],
     });
     itemcount += 14;
 }

  var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\sirslist\\sorteddata.txt", true);
 sw.WriteLine(sorted);            
 sw.Close();
```